# '#pragma once' equivalent for urdf/xacro files

Tags: rviz, urdf, xacro, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have multiple urdf files representing different components of a robot. As I don't want to define materials multiple times in different files, I created a file containing those definitions ('materials.urdf.xacro'). The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot>

    <material name="Black">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="Blue">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.8 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="Green">
        <color rgba="0.0 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="Grey">
        <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="DarkGrey">
        <color rgba="0.1 0.1 0.1 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="Orange">
        <color rgba="${255/255} ${108/255} ${10/255} 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="Brown">
        <color rgba="${222/255} ${207/255} ${195/255} 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="Red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

    <material name="White">
        <color rgba="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
    </material>

</robot>
```

I include them via

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find package_name)/urdf/materials.urdf.xacro" />
```

in a component file ('laser.urdf.xacro') and in the robot definition file ('robot.urdf.xacro') with itself includes 'laser.urdf.xacro').

When I try to run the urdf file via rviz, I get an error:

```
material 'Black' is not unique.
```

I presume it's due to the indirect second include of the 'materials.urdf.xacro' file, just like the problems you would have in C++ without '#pragma once' or the '#ifndef ... => #define ... => #endif' construct.

So is there an equivalent to this in urdf/xacro files?

- ROS Kinetic
- Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304797/%27#pragma-once%27-equivalent-for-urdf/xacro-files/) by [Julian98](https://answers.ros.org/users/33845/julian98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of this kind of workaround and it doesn't seem possible.

What you can do is instead of having multiple `<xacro:include ..../>` tags in all of your urdf files is to can create a new file like `standalone.urdf.xacro` (i usually do `my_robot_name_standalone.urdf.xacro`) and inside it you only use the `<xacro:include../>` to add all of your `urdf` files (which have no includes anymore). With that you ensure to avoid multiple inclusions. Here's an exemple :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_robot"
       xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find my_robot_description)/urdf/common_properties.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:include filename="$(find my_robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro" />
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-04**:
FYI: the `playerstage` stuff is not needed any longer.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-04**:
Okay I didn't know that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I presume it's due to the indirect second include of the 'materials.urdf.xacro' file, just like the problems you would have in C++ without '#pragma once' or the '#ifndef ... => #define ... => #endif' construct.
>
> So is there an equivalent to this in urdf/xacro files?

Not that I know of.

Personally I work around this by using "anonymous" materials and using a macro to create them. See [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/992e4d85d9f026749e90d08e3e509e0ce5e6f5b0/fanuc_resources/urdf/common_materials.xacro#L5-L9) for an example.

It's actually an error from the URDF parser, not xacro itself (it doesn't care).

You may also want to look into namespace support in xacro.

---

Edit: I've never tried it, but perhaps the [conditional support](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Conditional_Blocks) in xacro can now prevent pieces of xacro from being evaluated. You could use that to wrap everything in a `xacro:if` and then set a `xacro:property` inside the body.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2